# Am I understanding the stack? please correct me

Tags: variables, memory, assembly, x86, stack

I have this code written in c:

```
int main(){
  double x, y;
  int a, b, c;
  int *p;
```

and I have:

```
sizeof(int)=4
sizeof(double)=8
```

Is the memory structure sth like this?
More detailed in graphical mode:

```
IN MEMORY:(whole memory)
  LE = Little Endian  (INTEL)
  BE = Big Endian     (MIPS)

                                                  ------------------
                                    0x00000000   |                  | ?
                                                  ------------------
                                         .                 .
                                         .                 .
                                         .                 .
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff60   |  64(LE)  00(BE)  | 
                                                  ------------------
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff61   |  ff(LE)  12(BE)  | 
                                                  ------------------
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff62   |  12(LE)  ff(BE)  | 
                                                  ------------------
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff63   |  00(LE)  64(BE)  | 
                                                  ------------------

                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff64   | 00(LE)   00(BE)  |  c         if c = 256        (base10)
                                                  ------------------                c = 0x00000100 (base16)
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff65   | 01(LE)   00(BE)  |  c   0x0012ff64 points to c variable
                                                  ------------------       0x0012ff64 is a pointer
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff66   | 00(LE)   01(BE)  |  c
                                                  ------------------
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff67   | 00(LE)   00(BE)  |  c 
                                                  ------------------
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff68   |                  |  b
                                                  ------------------
                                                           .
                                                           .
                                                           .
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff6c   |                  |  a
                                                  ------------------
                                                           .
                                                           .
                                                           .
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff70   |                  |  y
                                                  ------------------
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff71   |                  |  y
                                                  ------------------  
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff72   |                  |  y
                                                  ------------------
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff73   |                  |  y
                                                  ------------------
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff74   |                  |  y
                                                  ------------------
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff75   |                  |  y
                                                  ------------------
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff76   |                  |  y
                                                  ------------------
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff77   |                  |  y
                                                  ------------------
                                                          .
                                                          .
                                                          .
                                                  ------------------
                                    0x0012ff78   |                  |  x
                                                  ------------------
                                                          .
                                                          .
                                                          .
                                                  ------------------
                                    0xfffffffff  |                  |  ?
                                                  ------------------
```

**My question:**
when we push sth into stack, do we do this?
[image]

1) I mean we push data at the end of stack with higher value of address?

2) or we push data at the top of stack with lower value of address?

3)how many addresses of memory each stack take?It depends on what?

Thanks

Comment: The ebb register doesn't point to the return instruction pointer but rather to the previous function's ebp

Comment: Don't forget that compiler can (and probably will) store local variables in registers - some or all of them may not be on the stack at all.

Comment: Note that even the meaning of the EBP register may be compiler dependent: When using optimizations EBP may even not be used at all. In most cases however the stack on x86 machines works like you understood it. However on x86 all data is little endian!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***On an x86 machine***, if the compiler isn't doing anything extraordinary, the stack will grow downwards.  On a `push` the stack pointer will decrement by the size of the push, and the `push`ed data will go onto the lower addresses of the stack.

On a `pop` the stack pointer will increment by the size of the pop.

I'm not commenting on MIPS, even though you mentioned it in your question, because:

1. I don't know anything about MIPS architecture
2. your question is tagged `x86`.

Regarding the size of each variable on the stack, that's 100% compiler dependent, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: Ok I don't care to `MIPS` really, did I write the memory structure for `INTEL` correctly? I have 3 question in my post and I would be thankful if you answer in more detail :)

Comment: He also asked about the (total) size (I think). This is chosen by the compiler (and often limited by the operating system). In `gcc` you can change it with the `--stack` option. A typical value on modern machines is 1 MB; modern Linux often has a limit of 10 MB (`ulimit -s`).

Comment: @MortezaLSC: It looks pretty much ok. Also, note that you asked **two** questions, as (1) and (2) are the inverse of each other.

Comment: @ Nathan Fellman So this is not important at the top or end of stack..the point is `the pushed data will go onto the lower addresses of the stack`. right?

Comment: In my understanding of memory I show addresses from `0x00000000` at top to `0xfffffffff` at down..but the image is something else...yes? :(

Comment: @MortezaLSC: the actual addresses depend on the values of the Stack Segment register (`SS`) and the initial value of the Stack Pointer (`ESP`).  In general, you'd be ill-advised to make assumptions on these values.